# How to share file environment across many projects?

Tags: javascript, python, git, github

I'm not sure to be in the right place for asking this question...

The problem is : We have many react projects (github) that share the same url's to get data from our API. There's many variables's url like this :

```
URI_DEV:
    API_1_FOO: api.dev.foo.com
    ...
URI_QUAL:
    API_1_FOO: api.qual.foo.com
    ...
```

In each project, we define this file with the same variable.

My question is : there is another solution to share this file more efficiency ? Like an dependecy each project pull or somethings like this ?

Comment: Are they all Node projects, perhaps?  Could make a Node module if it is.

Comment: Thnks. Nop, we use react in front and flask in back

Comment: Git submodule will do the trick. Keep that variable file alone as submodule that you can incorporate in other projects

Comment: [Node modules](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/creating-node-modules) should work fine for react. You don't need to use node on the backend server. Presumably you do use npm to install dependencies for your react apps. So you can create your own custom module and include it as a dependency to all your react apps.

Comment: Yes but we wan't share our URI in npm modules...